# SAS split dataset and export them into one Excel file

Tags: arrays, excel, macros, sas

I am trying to split a dataset into several datasets and then export them into one Excel file with multiple tabs. Here is what I tried:

```
%let term1=2010;
%let new1=newa;
%let new2=newb;
%let dim_new=2;

%let school1=schoola;
%let school2=schoolb;
%let dim_school=2;

%macro split;
    %do n=1 %to &dim_new;
        %do m=1 %to &dim_school;
            data retention&term1._new&n._school&m;
                set retention&term1;
                if new_student="new&n" and acad_group="school&m" then output;
            run;
        %end;
    %end;
%mend;

%macro exportresult;
    %do n=1 %to &dim_new;
        %do m=1 %to &dim_school;
            libname datadir "B:\report";
            proc export data=retention&term1._new&n._school&m
            outfile="B:\report\retention&term1._new&n"
            dbms=xlsx replace;
            sheet="school&m";
            run;
        %end;
    %end;
%mend;

%split;
%exportresult;
```

I got zero observation in each dataset. And the exported Excel only has the last school. I thought it can have two tabs.

Can anyone help me to figure why?

Thank you!

Comment: What values are in `new_student`?  `"new1"` or `"newa"`?  It would be helpful if you could make up some data that would work for this and put it in the question so we can more clearly see what's going on, but that question is probably a pointer to the problem I suspect.

Comment: What version of SAS do you have? Have you looked at ODS Excel or ODS Tagsets.ExcelXP?

Comment: Yep, the version of SAS is probably why the last school issue is happening.

Comment: new_student value has "First-Time-Freshmen", "New Transfer", "New Master". acad_group value has "ArtSchool", "EngineeringSchool" and so on. Actually I have 5 kinds of new_student and 11 schools. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have SAS 9.3 TS Level 1M2

Comment: I will check up ODS Excel or ODS Tagsets.ExcelXP. Thank you all!

Comment: I got it. new&n and school&m are actually another two macro variable. I need to add & infront of them, &new&n, &school&m. Then I got datasets with observations.

Comment: So to add extra tabs in the same excel file is SAS 9.4 feature? I might upgrade my version of SAS?